# Unity, Visual Studio Inconsistent Line Ending

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

This seems to be the most common issue with Unity & Visual Studio, and I looked through the internet and no one has permanently fixed it. Do you know of a solution that will permanently fix this issue with "inconsistent line endings", for Windows?

The 3 alternatives I've found is:

1) Go into "Advanced save options" each time when saving a VS file and save as Windows line ending.

2) Go into Unity-->Editor-->Data-->Resources-->And change NewBehaviourScript.cs; however, I cannot as they are non-modifiable files, i.e. I get "access denied each time", and I'm the administrator of my computer.

3)Ignore the line ending warnings. However, it slows down my Unity folder and the warning gets frustrating 100 times later.

So, any permanent solutions for "inconsistent line endings"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you are administrator of the computer does not mean you ran the program as an administrator. Programs don't get administrative rights unless you go though a UAC prompt, even if you are an administrator. Go try #2 again but start whatever program you will be using to edit the file as an administrator by right clicking on the icon and choosing "Run as administrator" then open the file and you can save it.

You also could do a "Save As" to some other folder then just copy the file by hand after it is saved.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I had to go into properties of the file--> then change user permission, to make the file editable for user. Then voila.